# HttpInterceptor not firing on some calls with Observables

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors, rxjs-observables, combinelatest, httpinterceptor

I'm working in Angular 11 and I built an HttpInterceptor whose job is to create custom error toast whenever an http request fails.

I've been testing the interceptor by forcing bad requests to my server and I encounter no issues, with toasts appearing correctly, but when I test 5xx errors, only some requests get intercepted by Angular's HttpInterceptor although my console logs errors for every one of them. Does anyone know where's the issue?

**Interceptor**

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    //sets the header of the intercepted request so it can be logged later
    const headers = req.headers;
    
    //handle responses
    return next.handle(req)
    .pipe(
      catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          console.log(req, error)  
          
          if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
              //shows a toast interface based on the error
          }
     })
}
```

**One of the requests not getting intercepted**

```
getPatientRiskFactors(patientId: string): Observable<type> {
    return this.store$.select(selectConfigFile).pipe(
      switchMap(cfg => {
        let url = cfg.configFile.backend.base_url;
        let queryParams = [
        //params
        ];
        return super.http.post<type[]>(url, queryParams, opt)
          .pipe(
            map(val => //array to item))
          );
      })
    )
  }
```

**Call to the request**

When I initialize this component, I request multiple data from my server so I used combineLatest to join the observable of each call. I get to intercept only one of these calls, while the others are just logged by the console.

```
this.obsElements$ = combineLatest([
      this.patientsService.getPatientDetail(this.patientId)
        .pipe(
          map(val=>val[0])
        ),
      this.patientsService.getPatientAllergyList(this.patientId),
      this.patientsService.getPatientRiskFactors(this.patientId),
      this.patientsService.getPatientsList()
    ]);
```

Comment: Do the same requests get intercepted with 4XX errors? if not, I think the problem is where you declared the intercept, probably a diff module context.

Comment: Yes, if I try, for example, to force bad requests to the server, I get 400 error and a toast popping up. The issue appears to be only with intercepting 5XX errors